# file.tell() doesn't update file size info for samba files

Tags: python, python-2.7, samba

File size parameter stop updated with python's `tell()` method for the files shared with samba.

I've created a sample to reproduce this problem.
`tell()` - always show the same size
while `os.stat` keep updating the value

````py
import time
import os

fname = "SAMBA_FILE_PATH"
with open(fname, 'r') as file_handler:
    while 1:
        file_handler.seek(0, 2)
        file_size = file_handler.tell()
        print file_size
        print os.stat(fname).st_size
        time.sleep(2)```
````

Comment: seems like an issue not in Python itself but rather in either OS or samba behavior/configuration...

I have an Ubuntu18.04 node with the samba installed and Win 2008R2 where I try to access this share from.

I've noticed that file located in share folder is not being updated when accessing from Win machine. It's not being updated after I append smth to file (but when I overwrite the file - it updated successfully)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `readline()` here instead of `seek()`.

```
import time
import os

fname = "SAMBA_FILE_PATH"
with open(fname, 'r') as file_handler:
    while 1:
        file_handler.readline()
        file_size = file_handler.tell()
        print file_size
        print os.stat(fname).st_size
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: readline is not an option in my case. and it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

fixed with modifying samba config by adding
`oplocks = False`

taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425934/windows-clients-will-not-refresh-linux-samba-file-locally-if-reading-file-at-int)